# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'usd')

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull price data from the CoinGecko API and can't seem to troubleshoot this issue. I expected the script to pull the data and double checked what I could to make sure I wasn't missing something but I can't seem to identify what is causing this.

```
var steamx = document.getElementById("steam-exchange");

var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=steam-exchange&vs_currencies=usd",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response){
    steamx.innerHTML = response.steamExchange.usd;

});
```

I have called the script.js file before my closing body tag and called jsquery before closing the head tag.

Apologies in advance if this is a silly fix! Thank you kindly.

I expected the script to pull price data from the CoinGecko API but I keep getting those errors instead.

I then want to take the results of the API call and multiply it by 550 for another field in my HTML however I am not sure where to begin on this part.

Comment: Have you checked to see what the `response` actually looks like? You should be able to use the browser "Network" developer tool.

Comment: Also it's "crossDomain" not "scrossDomain"

Comment: I corrected the crossdomain typo, its not triggering a response at all at this point.

Comment: So you see the outgoing side of the request in the Network tab?

Comment: Try with `response['steam-exchange'].usd`

Comment: When I try that URL, the response comes back with an object, in which I see a "steam-exchange" property, not "steamExchange".

Comment: I tried @LouysPatriceBessette suggestion with no luck here is the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at Object

I can't use steam-exchange in that line without getting this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: exchange is not defined
    at Object.

Comment: The "Cannot set properties of null" error means that the element id fetched on the first line does not exist.

Comment: I then want to take the results of the API call and multiply it by 550 for another field in my HTML however I am not sure where to begin on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this:

```
steamx.innerHTML = response.steamExchange.usd;
```

to:

```
steamx.innerHTML = response['steam-exchange'].usd;
```

because the response does not contain `streamExchange` property but it only contains `steam-exchange` property. To get that property, use `response['steam-exchange']` instead of `response.steam-exchange`.

```js
var steamx = document.getElementById("steam-exchange");
var steamxNew = document.getElementById("steam-exchange-new");

var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=steam-exchange&vs_currencies=usd",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response){
    steamx.innerHTML = response['steam-exchange'].usd;
    steamxNew.innerHTML = response['steam-exchange'].usd * 550;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Result : <span id="steam-exchange"></span></div>
<div>Another Field : <span id="steam-exchange-new"></span></div>
```